# WPF container artifacts when content is more than container

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm creating styles for control and faced up a strange problem.

Just compare:

- The normal slider: [image: normal slider]
- What I get when I decrease image container: [image: slider with artifacts]

What this is? That's not my border, I'm not use any borders or something like that. It affect's not only images. It's just example. How avoid this behavior?

The code when I decreased container(Thumb) size:

```
<Track.Thumb>
    <Thumb x:Name="Thumb" Height="15" Width="15">
        <Thumb.Template>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Thumb">
                <Image Source="../Images/Player/slider_thumb.png" Height="17" Width="17" />
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Thumb.Template>
    </Thumb>
</Track.Thumb>
```

Comment: First thing I would do is to use [Snoop](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/) to inspect the Visual Tree in the running application to check out the state of UI elements. Then you can find what is causing that.

Comment: Upload the Images again please.

Comment: What wrong with images?

Comment: Did you try to not specify the `Height` and `Width` attributes of the `Image` control?

Comment: Yes, but as i said this is only example. This border shows up when something not doesn't fit in container. :( And Snoop doesn't see it:http://zaley.in/showimage.xml/513fb3df9ae50.png (now slider doesn't fit on vertical)